# Rails-Couldn't find Tweet without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make blog application.
I couldn't acquisition tweet id for params[:id].I would like to define instance variables in index action and use that for argument.
The problem happened because 『find』 is probably false.But It didn't solve.

```rb
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :move_to_index,except: [:index,:show]

    def index
        @tweets= Tweet.all.order(id: "DESC")
        @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])  # <=here!!!
        @like = Like.new
    end

.....  

    private
    def tweet_params
        params.require(:tweet).permit(:text)
    end    

    def move_to_index
            redirect_to action: :index unless user_signed_in?
    end    

end
```

```rb
    #tweets.index.html.erb
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= current_user.username %> hello!
<% end %>
<p class="sample14"></p>
<% @tweets.each do|tweet|%>
    <p><%= tweet.user_name %>さん</p>
    <p><%= tweet.text %></p>
    <%= date_format(tweet.created_at) %>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
            <% if current_user.id == tweet.user.id %> 
                <%= link_to 'edit', "/tweets/#{tweet.id}/edit", method: :get %>
            <% end %>
    <% end %>        
    <%= link_to "details","/tweets/#{tweet.id}",method: :get%>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <% if current_user.already_liked?(@tweet)%>  # <=here!!!
            <div class="good_button">
                <%=link_to image_tag("p1.jpeg"),"/goods",method: :post %>
            </div>    
        <% else %>
            <%= button_to 'delete like',tweet_like_path(@tweet),method: :delete%> 
        <% end %>
    <% end %>    
        <%= tweet.liked_users.count %>  
    <p class="sample14"></p>
<% end %>
```

Error  message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltHQQ.png)

Please tell me how to solve this problem

Comment: `params[:id]` returns `nil` and so there is problem. Basically when you probably trying to access `/tweets`, you are not passing `id` in params and so you won't get it in the line you are getting error. Question: Why you want to find tweet with an id in your `index` action?

Comment: Because I'm implementation like button(for example.. twitter) on index page and it has to save tweet id(liked) , user id(like tweet).

Comment: `index` action conventionally for listing resources(tweets in your case). If you want to like tweet, it should be handled in separate action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you really know what you're doing you may want to move this logic:

```
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id])  # <=here!!!
```

... into a separate show method. Because usually index would list Tweets and show would show a Tweet

But you can also add:

```
    @tweet = Tweet.find(params[:id]) if params[:id]
```

To check the parameter is actually passed, which is where your error comes from when it's not.